# Windows Store App XAML Gridview not rendering data

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have the following `GridView` which is bound to my ViewModel

XAML Code:

```
<GridView SelectionMode="None" ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2.5 3" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ProductList}" Visibility="{Binding IsGridView, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
                          SizeChanged="SetListItemsWidth" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:ProductListControl Tag="{Binding id}" Margin="3 0 3 3" Tapped="GotoProduct"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>
```

Model:

```
 public class ProductC1View : INotifyPropertyChanged
 { 
 public string ScreenTitle
    {
        get { return _ScreenTitle; }
        set
        {
            _ScreenTitle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ScreenTitle");
        }
    }
   public ObservableCollection<ProductDisplay> ProductList { get; set; }
   }
```

VIEWMODEL:

```
class ProductC1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ProductC1ViewModel()
    {
        this.View = new ProductC1View();
    }
    private async void ApplyFilter(object obj)
    {
        View.ProductList.Clear();
        View.IsProductsAvailable = true;
   var lstData = await _objController.GetSubCategoryDetails(View);
        foreach (var product in lstData.catalogs)  
   View.ProductList.Add(_objHelper.FormatProductDisplayDetails(product));
    }
}
```

The `GridView` is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. Everything works fine on Intial load or after appending new items to the collection.

But when I clear the items in the collection in case of applying filter on the data and add new items to the collection the `GridView` doesn't render data. The Underlying Viewmodel(ProductList) contains the data. I can bind it to a ListView and it works. Only for Gridview it doesn't render

And if I change the ItemsPanel of the gridview from ItemsWrapGrid to Stackpanel then its working, but I can't use Stackpanel since I want the list to be displayed by one item stacked next to each other like in Amazon app.

The weird case is it works in Windows 8.1 Phone app but doesn't work in Windows 10. Any help?

[image: Expected]

Comment: You say the `GridView` is bound to the data source, but it doesn't seem there is any `ItemsSource` binding in the XAML. Could you post the code in the ViewModel, especially how you set up the binding and how you do the clearing?

Comment: Visibility="{Binding IsGridView..." Best and most revelant property name ever !
As Martin Zikmund said you do not set the binding ItemsSource on your GridView, so you can't benefit of the RaisePropertyChanged which is in charge of refreshing your gridview

Comment: @yanyankelevich Missed the binding property in the code snippet, have updated with snippets for VM, and Model
User can switch between List-type View and Grid-type view for the data set, hence the property "IsGridView"

Comment: @Prince I had no doubt that this IsGridView was intended to tell if you have to display a grid or something else. it's just that to me it doesn't looks like a godd variable name. Because there is no answer to the question "what is grid view ?" something like HasToDisplayGridView would be slightly better but i have no knowledge of your intent in this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of got a temporary fix for this, changed the Itemspanel to wrapgrid and it's working now

```
 <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapGrid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add RaisePropertyChanged (require Mvvmlight) in ProductList setter.

```
private ObservableCollection<ProductDisplay> _productList;
 public ObservableCollection<ProductDisplay> ProductList
 {
     get
        {
            return _productList;
        }
    set
        {
            _productList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(()=>ProductList);
        }
 }
```

Or staying with just INotifyPropertyChanged you need to implement the PropertyChangedEventHandler ( like in this tutorial):

```
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

private ObservableCollection<ProductDisplay> _productList;
public ObservableCollection<ProductDisplay> ProductList
     {
         get
            {
                return _productList;
            }
        set
            {
                _productList = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
     }
```

And you don't necessary need a GridView to display tiles of pictures :

```
<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding AllDesignSheetsInDB}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentDesignSheet}"  BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  >
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ProductListControl Tag="{Binding id}" Margin="3 0 3 3" Tapped="GotoProduct"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: No this doesn't seems to work, the underlying ProductList has the data and when I display it in a Listview it works, the problem is only with Gridview in Windows 10 device

Comment: And if I change the ItemsPanel of the gridview from ItemsWrapGrid to Stackpanel then its working, but I can't use Stackpanel since I want the list to be displayed by one item stacked next to each other.

Comment: I'm actually doing that "INotifyPropertyChanged ", the problem seems to be with the Gridview itemspanel because  if I change the ItemsPanel of the gridview from ItemsWrapGrid to Stackpanel then its working, but I can't use Stackpanel since I want the list to be displayed by one item stacked next to each other.